# Can't Load more pdf files dynamically using PDFView.open in pdf.js

Tags: pdf, mozilla, pdf.js

I have a select box for file selection. If the file selected from select box, it passes through `PDFView.open(selected file path);`. It opens the pdf file. Fine.

But if this selection process continues more than 10 times, it doesn't load pdf file further which means it doesn't enter into open function.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Note: This issue happen only in Mozila browser, in Chrome file loading works fine

Comment: Can you show a link to an example that demonstrates the problem you're describing? (PS. cross-posted at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4027)

Comment: How to close the previous document before load a new one? Is there any idea?

Comment: The `Worker` instance is currently now exposed. As a work-around, you could disable web workers by setting `PDFJS.disableWorker = true;`. This may degrade the performance of your app, though.